# How to Create Separated 1D Kernels for Each Subdataset and Backpropagate Them in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have 5 datasets of 1D signals and would like to apply 1D kernels for each signal separately, followed by concatenation and flattening, to feed them into same neural network. My code:

```
initial_kernels = [
    tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([1, 1, 3, 1]), trainable=True),  # Kernel for row 1
    tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([1, 1, 3, 1]), trainable=True),  # Kernel for row 2
    tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([1, 1, 3, 1]), trainable=True),  # Kernel for row 3
    tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([1, 1, 3, 1]), trainable=True),  # Kernel for row 4
    tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([1, 1, 3, 1]), trainable=True)  # Kernel for row 5
]

convolved_outputs = []
convolved_outputs.append(Conv2D(kernel_size=(1, 3), activation='relu', filters=1)(signal1 * initial_kernels[0]))
convolved_outputs.append(Conv2D(kernel_size=(1, 3), activation='relu', filters=1)(signal2 * initial_kernels[1]))
convolved_outputs.append(Conv2D(kernel_size=(1, 3), activation='relu', filters=1)(signal3 * initial_kernels[2]))
convolved_outputs.append(Conv2D(kernel_size=(1, 3), activation='relu', filters=1)(signal4 * initial_kernels[3]))
convolved_outputs.append(Conv2D(kernel_size=(1, 3), activation='relu', filters=1)(signal5 * initial_kernels[4]))

flattened_outputs = Flatten()(convolved_outputs)

# Define the rest of your model architecture
model = Sequential([
    Dense(units=4096, activation='relu'),
    Dense(units=2048, activation='relu'),
    Dense(units=1024, activation='relu'),
    Dense(units=256, activation='relu'),
    Dense(units=1)
])

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=lr), loss='mse')

history = model.fit(flattened_outputs, y_train, batch_size=256, epochs=100)
```

However, the code is not working, and I get:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__Mul_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} Incompatible shapes: [22361,1,53,1] vs. [1,1,3,1] [Op:Mul]
```